# Spring Cache with Spring Data Rest Repository is caching results of save on exception

Tags: spring, caching, repository

I have a Spring Data Rest repository that I would like to use Spring Caching with it.

The cache works as expected when there are no errors.  However, when the result of the save is a validation exception, the entity is cached, even though it is not written to the database.

SDR Repository

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "businessUnits", path = "businessUnits")
public interface BusinessUnitRepository extends JpaRepository<BusinessUnit, UUID> {

@Override
@Cacheable(value = "lookups", cacheManager = "vaultCache")
BusinessUnit findOne(final UUID id);

@Override
@CacheEvict(value = "lookups", cacheManager = "vaultCache", allEntries = true, beforeInvocation = true)
BusinessUnit save(BusinessUnit entity);
```

If I POST the message body below a new Business Unit it is saved correctly.  The first GET to retrieve the record hits the database as expected and subsequent GETs come from the cache.

```
{
"name": "Test_Business_2",
"effectiveDate": "2019-12-16T11:11:11.111+0000",
"expirationDate": "2020-12-16T11:11:11.111+0000",
"businessUnitType": "/businessUnitTypes/38faf33c-5454-4245-bc69-2b31e510fa6b"
}
```

The BusinessUnit Entity has a not null on the effectiveDate field.

```
@NotNull
@Column(name = "effective_date")
private Timestamp effectiveDate;
```

When I PATCH the business unit with a null effectiveDate.  The response is an error, an exception is logged and the database is not updated.

```
{
"effectiveDate": null
}
```

When I query the db, I see the record was not updated

```
NAME            EFFECTIVE_DATE      EXPIRATION_DATE
Test_Business_2,2019-12-16 06:11:11,2020-12-16 06:11:11
```

However, when I do a GET on the businessUnits endpoint.  The database is not hit to read the record, and the null effectiveDate is returned.

```
{
"createDate": "2017-02-20T13:38:00.386+0000",
"lastModifiedDate": "2017-02-20T13:38:00.386+0000",
"effectiveDate": null,
"expirationDate": "2020-12-16T11:11:11.111+0000",
"name": "Test_Business_2",  ...
```

So, it seems the data that caused the exception to be thrown, is stored in cache.

What do I need to change so that the value is not saved in cache when the database is not updated on save?

I appreciate any help or advice.  Thanks.

Comment: I have not found a solution to my problem, but I did find a work around.  In the case where I see the error an exception is being thrown, but the cache is not being evicted.  In the method that handles the exception, I can programmatically clear the cache.

   
    Cache cache = cacheManager.getCache("lookups");
    cache.clear();

Then the cache is cleared, and does not contain the "exception" value.

Answer (score 1):

The [key](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/Cacheable.html#key--) you cache and the [key](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/CacheEvict.html#key--) you evict don't match. You need to define how to get the id from the `BusinessUnit`, for example:

```
@CacheEvict(key = "#entity.id"
```

Or provide a [`KeyGenerator`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/KeyGenerator.html) that understands your domain model.

Comment: I get the same result regardless of the beforeInvocation setting.  I have tried it setting it to true, and to false.